# Como mudar texto dependendo do valor retornado da api em tabela no ReactJS

Tags: react

Criei uma tabela usando o componente ReactTable e estou alimentando ela com dados vindos de uma api. Um desses dados retorna como 0 ou -1 e eu quero tratar eles para que se vier 0 apareça escrito "Ativado" na tabela, se for -1 que seja "Desativado". Sou novo em ReactJS e não sei bem como fazer, podem me dar uma ajuda?

Segue o código:

```
class DataTable extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          dadosGrupo:'',
        }

        this.state = {
          isShowing: false
        }

        this.state = {
          status:''
        }  

      }

  componentDidMount(){
    const url ='http://xxx'
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET'
    }).then(response => response.json())
      .then(dados => {
      this.setState({dadosGrupo: dados})
    })
    .then(Inativo => {this.setState({status:Inativo})})


  }

  openModalHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
        isShowing: true
    });
}

closeModalHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
        isShowing: false
    });
} 



    render(){

        const columns = [
            {
              Header: "Status",
              accessor: "Inativo",
              style:{
                textAlign:"center",
                color:'white',
                  },
                width:100,
                maxWidth:100,
                minWidth:100,
                Cell: props => {
                  return(
                    <div>
                {this.state.inativo === 0 ? <div style={{color:'green'}}>Ativado</div> : <div style={{color:'red'}}>Desativado</div>}
                    </div>
                  )
                }


            },

            {
              Header: "Cdgrupo",
              accessor: "Cdgrupo",
              style:{
                  textAlign:"center"
                    },
                  width:100,
                  maxWidth:100,
                  minWidth:100,

                },      

            {
             Header: "Grupo",
             accessor: "Grupos",
             sortable: false
           },
           {
             Header: "Ação",
             sortable: false,
             filterable:false,
             width:100,
             maxWidth:100,
             minWidth:100,
             style:{
                 textAlign:"Center"
             },
             Cell: props =>{
                 return(
                   <div>
                   {this.state.isShowing ? <div  className="backdrop2"  ></div> : null }
                     <button className='modaleditar btn btn-info' onClick={this.openModalHandler}>Editar</button>
                   </div>
                 )

             },

           },
          ]

        return(
            <div>
    <ReactTable

    columns={columns}
    data={this.state.dadosGrupo}
    filterable
    defaultPageSize={10}
    noDataText={"Não foi possível carregar os dados."}
    >

    </ReactTable>

    <ModalEdit
            className="modal"
            show={this.state.isShowing}
            close={this.closeModalHandler}>

           </ModalEdit>

    </div>
        )
    }
}

export default DataTable;
```

O Status que eu criei no state e a condicional dentro de columns foi apenas para testar essa condicional, eu imagino que seja por ela que será feito isso correto?

A tabela está retornando assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se for necessário colocar mais informações é só dizer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Você precisa resolver esse problema como está descrito na documentação do componente](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table#data)
[react-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table) que é pela `resolveData` como exemplo minimo demonstrado logo abaixo:

```js
const columns = [
        {
            Header: 'Name',
            accessor: 'name'
        },
        {
            Header: 'Status',
            accessor: 'status'
        }
    ];

    const data = [
        {
            name: 'Tanner Linsley',
            status: 1,
        },
        {
            name: 'Geovana Sturt',
            status: 0,
        }
    ];  

<ReactTable 
    data={data}
    columns={columns} 
    resolveData={r => r.map((item) => {
        return {name:item.name, status:item.status===1?'Ativado':'Desativado'};
    })}
/>
```

***Observação:*** *se por acaso precisar mexer só em um item e precisar copiar o resto faça da seguinte forma*:

```js
return {...item, status:item.status===1?'Ativado':'Desativado'};
```

onde `...item` copia o objeto original e muda somente o que precisa, ou até cria um novo item nesse objeto.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Virgilio, da forma que você mostou de fato funciona mas no caso esses valores 0 e -1 são passados de uma api por json, então o ideal é que eu trate esse Ativado/Desativado para todos os objetos que vierem no json de uma vez só em vez de criar um por um. Seguindo o raciocinio do seu exemplo é possivel?

Comment: @GabrielMidão se você recebe esse API de terceiros, o dados já vem assim, se é você que tem esse API sim você já pode construir o seu resultado da maneira que quiser. Pelo que eu entendi é de terceiros (só me confirme) se for, a resposta que eu te dei é a resposta que precisa, porque o próprio Componente já faz o papel de alterar isso para você dando a possibilidade como demonstrado acima. Um outro ponto é que eu respondi a pergunta do jeito que está na original, então qualquer outro tipo de duvida de maior valor não é bem visto aqui porque altera a razão original da respostas invalidando.....

Comment: continuando @GabrielMidão se a resposta respondeu a duvida da pergunta marque a resposta que te ajudou, e depois faça uma nova pergunta para uma nova duvida. Obrigado.

Comment: Sim, é de terceiros. Se eu entendi direito, da forma que você mostrou eu teria que criar de um em um correto? Se for o caso é inviavel pois são mais de 150 objetos vindos da API. O que eu estou procurando entender é  como fazer que mude no momento em que eu faço a requisição para a API usando o Axios.

Comment: @GabrielMidão é uma única fez! Você não entendeu o exemplo com certeza.

Comment: @GabrielMidão se na API de terceiros não tem essa possibilidade é assim que resolve recriando o objeto mas, isso é uma linha para o Javascript e também em nenhum momento disse quem é a API, qual é a documentação, o endereço e isso não faz parte da sua pergunta original. Mas, é assim que te mostrei como resolve e também é proposto pelo Componente

Comment: Li novamente o seu exemplo com mais atenção e consegui resolver, muito obrigado e me perdoe por qualquer coisa Virgilio!